# How to get Python code to work on VPS web application

Tags: python, ssh, vps

My team and I have set up an account with Hostinger and have a VPS set up with its own domain. Our current Operating System is CentOS 7 64bit with Webmin/Virtualmin/LAMP and we have Webmin set up as our Cpanel. As of right now we have our HTML pages showing but our Python code is not working.

We used SSH to download Python3, MongoDB, pymongo, and flask, but are still having trouble getting our Python code to work on our web application. From here we are unsure what to do and need guidance on what our next steps should be. Thank you in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you've gone for on your VPS is a web hosting setup rather than a bare metal VPS setup. I can see why you think you'd want web hosting, but in reality Flask works differently in that it is its own application which needs to run rather than being served like an HTML page.

There is an excellent tutorial on how to do this [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04). It is designed for Ubuntu (which is a good setup if you are starting fresh) but there are also versions for different linux flavours.